# не срабатывает код по вложенным подзапросам в WHERE

Tags: sql

Задача:Посчитайте среднюю стоимость аренды фильма каждого возрастного рейтинга. Среди них найдите рейтинг с самыми дорогими для аренды фильмами.
Выведите на экран названия категорий фильмов с этим рейтингом. Добавьте второе поле со средним значением продолжительности фильмов категории.
Запрос:

```
    SELECT c.name, AVG(length) 
FROM film_category as fc
JOIN category as c on fc.category_id=fc.category_id
JOIN movie as m on fc.film_id=m.film_id
where rating = (SELECT rating
FROM movie as m
GROUP BY m.rating
ORDER BY rating DESC
LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY c.name
```

Comment: я уже голову сломала(((( Два запроса по отдельности работают, а как их объединить не могу сообразить, от слова совсем(((((

Comment: У вас по-моему просто в `JOIN`-ах ошибка. Строка `fc.category_id=fc.category_id` всегда истинна. Тут, видимо, имеется ввиду вместо одного `fc` просто `c`.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую.